# Wildfly flush cache of security-domain

Tags: caching, jboss, wildfly, flush, securitydomain

Im have a war project with JAX-RS interface deployed on wildfly and there is a security-domain configured, which loads user password and role from db. The security-domain uses cache-type=default. Updates of authenticated users are not recognized by the security-domain, because the old data are cached. I verified this with the jboss-cli.sh. So how can I remove a specific user from the cache? I want to do this within the deployed application and not via jboss-cli.sh.

Comment: Which version of WildFly are you using?

Comment: it's wildfly 8.2.0.final

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue may be related to a bug in WildFly: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3221.

There is a workaround to explicitly flush the authentication cache:

```
@WebListener
public class SessionInvalidationListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Inject
    private Principal principal;

    @Resource(name = "java:jboss/jaas/mydomain/authenticationMgr")
    private CacheableManager<?, Principal> authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        // not used
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        authenticationManager.flushCache(principal);
    }
}
```

I've tested this approach in a slightly different use case. The interesting bit is accessing the `authenticationManager` - it should be easy to adapt that to your situation.

The bug should be fixed in WildFly 9.x (I didn't check).

Comment: I don't use sessions, so this bug does not affect my problem. I just want to flush the cache of my security-domain and that's totally what your solution does :) Tanks! I got a new issue and open a new thread therefore.

Comment: Any idea on how to flush the cache across multiple instances of Wildfly? Either running in standalone or domain mode?

Comment: This is the most accurate answer for the caching problem I was facing even on Wildfly11

Answer (score 1):

In Wildfly 10 using Domain Mode you can clear cache for security domains very easily by using jboss-cli on the following way:

First connect to Domain Controller by using

```
./jboss-cli.sh --connect controller={domainhost}:9990 --user={username} --password={password}
```

Then execute command

```
/host={hostname}/server={instancename}/subsystem=security/security-domain={securityname}:flush-cache
```

If security domain is defined like this:

```
<security-domain name="ldap-test" cache-type="default">
```

command will look like this:

```
/host=wf-server-1/server=instance-1/subsystem=security/security-domain=ldap-test:flush-cache
```

The similar solution should work for Standalone Mode.

Comment: In standalone the command looks like this `jboss-cli.sh -c --controller=127.0.0.1:9990 --user={username} --password={password} --command="/subsystem=security/security-domain=ldap-test:flush-cache"`

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the attribute 'cache-type=default' from the security-domain, no cache will be used.
See also here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Security+subsystem+configuration